# How to access the SharePoint site in my Asp.net application?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, jquery

I want to fetch the SharePoint List in my Asp.net Application.How can I do using JavaScript or Jquery?

Comment: This link will help you http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/128644/read-sharepoint-list-data-from-an-aspx-website-c

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to use the SharePoint web services to access the SharePoint lists from your application (regardless what's the technology that you use) as the following:

- Create a service reference to access SharePoint lists
- Open or create a Visual Studio project.
- In Solution Explorer, right-click the References node, and then click Add Service Reference.
- In the Address box, type the URL to the target site and append /_vti_bin/ListData.svc. For example, the address for the site intranet.wingtip.com would be http://intranet.wingtip.com/_vti_bin/ListData.svc.
- Change the default name in the Namespace box from ServiceReference1 to something more appropriate, such as WingtipSite.
- Click OK to create proxy classes, including a data context and entity classes for the lists that you want to access.
- Begin writing code against these proxy classes, which provide strongly typed access to the columns of SharePoint list items.

For more details check

- [Adding values to SharePoint lists](https://www.codeproject.com/kb/sharepoint/sharepointlistwebservice.aspx)
- [Accessing SharePoint Lists by Using WCF Data Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh134614(v=office.14).aspx)

You can also use SharePoint client-side object model (CSOM) by referencing `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll` to your solution.

For basic operation check [Complete basic operations using SharePoint 2013 client library code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912(v=office.15).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

To get a SharePoint list using javascript:

```
var siteUrl = '/sites/MySiteCollection'; <-- URL of the web containing the list you are interested in
var listName = 'Documents'; <-- Name of the list you are interested in
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listName);
```

By now you have the SharePoint-list. If you are interested in the list items, you can get them using a caml-query to select the items you want.

```
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' + 
    '<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>');
var collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
```

You can read more about it here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185007(v=office.14).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201.aspx

Comment: This will not work from another domain than the SharePoint server

Comment: Good point. Didn't think it through. Still possible though, if not so wise, by adding some headers. :)